# Fallo al intentar actualizar, insertar o leer en wordpress utilizando variable global $wpdb

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy intentando realizar en WordPress, con PHP, unos métodos y clase que almacene los datos de las excepciones y errores que puedan ocurrir en wordpress. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
private function obtener_ultima_fecha($name, $file){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = "wp_excepciones_errores";

    $obtener_fecha = "SELECT FECHA FROM ".$table_name. "   WHERE MENSAJE = \"$name\" AND LOCALIZACION = \"$file\" ;";
    $resultado = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($obtener_fecha));
    return $resultado;
}


public function insertar_excepcion_error(Exception $ex){
     global $wpdb;
     $table_name = "wp_excepciones_errores";
    $this->crear_tabla_errores();

    $datos_insertar_tabla = [
        "Id_Exception" => null,
        "FECHA" =>date('d-m-Y'),
        "MENSAJE"=>$ex->getMessage(),
        "LOCALIZACION"=>$ex->getFile(),
        ];

        //Comprobamos que no existe en la bbdd
        $comprobacion = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT MENSAJE FROM ".$table_name);
        if(null == $comprobacion){
            $wpdb->insert($table_name, $datos_insertar_tabla);
            $this->set_last_report_date($this->obtener_ultima_fecha($ex->getMessage(),$ex->getFile()));
        }else{
            
            $this->set_last_report_date($this->obtener_ultima_fecha($ex->getMessage(),$ex->getFile()));
            $elementos_actualizar = ["FECHA" =>date('d-m-Y'),
            "LOCALIZACION"=>$ex->getFile(),
            "MENSAJE"=>$ex->getMessage()];
            $update_row = "UPDATE $table_name SET FECHA = %s, LOCALIZACION = %s WHERE MENSAJE = %s";
            $resultado_update = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($update_row, $elementos_actualizar));
            if(!$resultado_update){
                echo "Algo va mal";
            }else{
                echo "Va bien";
            }
        }
        
}

private function crear_tabla_errores(){
    global $wpdb;
    $tabla = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `botellas`.`wp_excepciones_errores`  ( `Id_Exception` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `FECHA` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , 
    `MENSAJE` VARCHAR(350) NOT NULL , 
    `LOCALIZACION` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id_Exception`)); ";

        $wpdb->query($tabla);
}
```

Los datos se obtienen de:

```
catch ( \ReflectionException $ex ) {
                
                
                NotificationManager::class; 
                $n = new NotificationManager("pepito@gmail.com");
                $n->insertar_excepcion_error($ex);
                
                return null;
            }
```

Aunque no me produce ningún error, sin embargo, a la hora de actualizar o de intentar obtener la fecha, siempre obtengo el valor 0 (fallo al actualizar) y *null* cuando intento obtener la fecha. He estado mirando la documentación y (creo) que no tengo fallos a la hora de realizar las funciones. ¿Por qué no me funciona? Gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Comment: Esto donde lo tienes, en functions.php o un custom plugin? Intenta verificando si el error esta en la consulta como en este ejemplo: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/365393/doing-wpdb-get-results-returns-null-doing-the-same-query-in-my-db-returns-cor

Comment: Si, funciona. Pero me parece curioso que me marque error de sql, cuando la sentencia es correcta. Gracias y un saludo. Tendré que seguir investigando